# Mount floppy disk image (*.img) as virtual floppy drive

Tags: images, disk-image, floppy, windows-98

Title says it all. I am looking for some software that will allow me to mount a floppy disk image (*.img) as a virtual floppy drive...similar I suppose to mounting an ISO image to a virtual optical drive.

I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.

**Edit:** I am using Windows 98 (...old, I know!)

Comment: Finding software that'll still work in Win98 still may be a lot harder than you think. try getting that img file loaded on a real floppy first, then get an old floppy drive, or usb floppy or something. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MDTGuy, got some old disk images of things like Microsoft QuickC which I want to install, without having to load 12 images to disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [Virtual Floppy Drive](http://vfd.sourceforge.net/) in the past.  Im fairly certain it supports .img files.

Comment: Thanks, but does not work with Win9x, however my machine dual boots with Win2k so using that

Comment: I was using it when I was working on Windows XP and 7. But I get BSOD in Windows 8...

Answer (score 1):

Try [**FileDisk**](http://branten.se/nt/) (also comes [bundled](http://www.winimage.com/misc/filedisk64.htm) with [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/download.htm)):

> FileDisk is a virtual disk driver for Windows that uses one or more files to emulate physical disks. A console application is included that let you dynamically mount and unmount files. An example of use for this driver is if you have made plans spending the weekend writing a RAID driver for NT but find you are short of disks. FileDisk can also use CD/DVD images.
>
> FileDisk will use sparse files as disk images if the underlying file system supports it. A sparse file is a file where suficiently large blocks of zeros aren't allocated disk space. To see how much disk space a file actually uses right click on the file and choose Properties. If you for example create a sparse file of 4GB, mount it in FileDisk and format it to NTFS, it will only take up 24MB on disk but look like a normal disk of 4GB. When you copy files to it the used disk space will automatically increase.

Usage:

```
filedisk /mount  <devicenumber> <filename> [size[k|M|G] | /ro | /cd] <drive:>
filedisk /umount <drive:>
filedisk /status <drive:>
```