# share file with VM which don't support guest additions

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, windows-95

I am running a windows 95 Virtual machine in virtualbox. I want to share a folder with it which is on the host machine. I have tried shared folders but they aren't supported without guest Additions. And windows 95 VM cannot also install the guest Additions. Is there any other way to share files with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the optical virtual CD rom of the Virtual machine. First download a tool named AnyBurn (http://www.anyburn.com/download.php). Tyen after installing, open it. Click create image from files/folders. Then add the files or folder and click next. Now choose ISO path and name. Then wait till ISO is created. When created start the virtual machine. Click Devices > hover on Optical Drive then click Choose disk image. Browse the ISO file and insert it. Then in windows 95, a message will come looking for SETUP.exe in the CD rom. Close it and open My Computer. Now right click the disk image and click Explore. That's it!

Comment: Nice! It worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To copy files *to* the virtual machine use a virtual CD or DVD, and to copy files *from* (and also *to*) the virtual machine use a virtual floppy disk. Before reading the steps below read first [how to add virtual disks to your virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#settings-storage).

#### Creating a CD image from files:

1. Download [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) (portable version [here](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/infrarecorder_portable)) and run it.
2. Click the **Data Disc** button to create a blank CD image (~700 MiB), or alternatively click the small **DVD** button next to it to create a blank DVD image (~4 GiB).
3. Drag and drop files into the lower **Disc Layout** panel.
4. Click the **Actions** menu > **Burn Compilation** > **to a Disc Image...** and choose where you want to save the resulting .ISO file.
5. In VirtualBox, start your virtual machine then click the **Devices** menu > **Optical Drives** > **Choose a disk file...** and choose the previously created .ISO file. The virtual machine will now detect a CD/DVD containing your files.

#### Creating a floppy disk image:

1. Start your virtual machine then click the **Devices** menu > **Floppy Drives** > **Choose/Create a disk image...**
2. Click the **Create** button and set...

   - **Filepath:** where you want to save the resulting .IMG file.
   - **Size:** 1.44M
   - **Format disk as FAT12**
3. The newly created image file will appear in the floppy disk list, click **Choose**. The virtual machine will now detect a blank floppy disk.
4. Copy files from your virtual machine to the virtual floppy disk, then on your host OS open the .IMG file with [7-Zip](https://7-zip.org/) and extract the files inside.
5. You can copy files *to* the virtual floppy disk from the host by [mounting the .IMG file](https://superuser.com/q/538440/1696651).

---

Note: Linux virtual machines can accept virtual floppy disks of any capacity, for example you can attach a [3.93 MB .IMG file](https://archive.org/download/floppy-144-288-393) (the largest floppy accepted by VirtualBox) to a Linux virtual machine and it will not complain. You can then extract the .IMG file on a Linux host using [LXQt Archiver](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-archiver).